# Flag messages as deleted for one user in conversation

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database schema like this:

```
conversation
    - id
    - created

user_has_conversation
    - user_id
    - conversation_id

message
    - id
    - user_id
    - conversation_id
    - text
```

How can I design these tables if one user decides to delete the conversation or some messages, but I want them to remain visible for the other user.

Should I create a new table called

```
message_deleted
    - user_id
    - message_id
```

And fill it with IDs of deleted messages?

Comment: My first thought was an addition field in your message table, which acts as `flag`. For example the inital value could be 1 for visible and if deleted change to  0. Based on that you should be able to create the right SQL queries...

Comment: You mean fill it with deleter-deleted id pairs.

Comment: What does user_id mean in table message? The creator? (Likely since other columns seem to be about messages independent of any user_id.) Because technically since user_id and message_id appear in the same table without being used for anything else they *could* be used as the many-to-many application relationship "[user_id] sees [message_id]. (In a probably horribly redundant way.) But presumably they're there for something else or you wouldn't have user_id there and you wouldn't have asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should use a table like you suggested:

> ```
> message_deleted
>     - user_id
>     - message_id
> ```

Your "being deleted" is a many-to-many relationship on user_id and message_id.

> if one user decides to delete the conversation or some messages, but I
>   want them to remain visible for the other user.

Similarly you would have a table for conversations:

```
conversation_deleted
    - user_id
    - conversation_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a flag 'visible' (default true) to the message table.

Comment: What if I post a message, then delete it. Visible will be set to 0. How do I know that I can show it to the other users in conversation?

Comment: I'll go like this: select * from mess where conv_id = ? and id not in ( select id from mess where visible = 0 and user_id = ? and conv_id = ? );